# best UI library for PHP

Tags: php

I am new to webdevelopment,we are developing a quiz game using PHP and MYSQL.I would like
to know what would be the best library for PHP for UI development. The library which could handle the compatablity issues across the browsers and provide rich UI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify whether you are looking for a Rich UI JavaScript framework or a PHP framework that generates the JavaScript of a particular JavaScript UI framework

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you for highlighting the difference, JQuery is one Javascript framework i found for rich UI, I would like to know the benefits of using a PHP Framework that generates Javascript.. what are the issues the framework could ideally handle??

Comment: well, the main benefit would be to being able to work in your prefered language. Kinda like GWT which lets you create the rich UI JavaScript code from Java. ExtJs for GWT comes to mind too. I am not sure if there is any PHP libraries that are similar to those though. Zend Framework has a few classes to generate Javascript for Dojo. But apart from that? It's a good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP has nothing to do with client-side UI thus there are no PHP libraries for this task. This is typically handled using JavaScript or CSS frameworks

Comment: JQuery is one library i found out?? would there be a better choice??

Comment: Go with jquery. easiest and powerful js lib.

Comment: Nowadays this doesn't stop people to make some UI libs in php that wraps HTML+CSS+JS like Telerik, Agile Toolkit, KoolPHPSuite, etc...

Comment: See [PHP view-components](https://github.com/view-components/view-components)

Answer (score 5):

The same quest has prompted me to start this project: [Agile UI](https://github.com/atk4/ui) - a PHP UI Component Library.

My goal is to let developers focus on the business tasks and use standard UI implementation for a web/responsive application. This won't solve 100% of use-cases, but it is a quick-and-effective solution. (For more complex scenarios, I recommend using ReactJS with RestAPI).

Agile UI is a relatively new project but it is maturing very quickly and you are welcome to try it out. There are no heavy dependencies and code is designed to work out-of-the-box.

1. `composer require atk4/ui`
2. Add this code to a file:

   include 'vendor/autoload.php';

   $app = new \atk4\ui\App('My App');
   $app->initLayout(new \atk4\ui\Layout\Admin());

   $db = \atk4\data\Persistence::connect($DSN);

   class User extends \atk4\data\Model {
       public $table = 'user';
       function init() {
           parent::init();

   ```
       $this->addField('name');
       $this->addField('email', ['required'=>true]);
       $this->addField('password', ['type'=>'password']);
   }
   ```

   }

   $app->layout->add(new \atk4\ui\CRUD())
     ->setModel(new User($db));

The result should look like this:

[image]